# jQuery collapse Div on hover

Tags: jquery, css

I have two divs side by side.On hover I want one of the div to take 100% of `width` and the other to collapse.

I made a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepy02/WYFH5/) - the transition is awkward as I am changing the width of the collapsing div and this changes the text indentation while collapsing.

I also tried `slideToggle` and `hide`, but in this case while expanding the div, the other div gets positioned below it (obviously because the sum of the width's is greaterthan 100%)

Any solutions to make the collapsing div slide/hide out without changing the div's contents indentation and position?

Thanks

Code:
HTML:

```
<div style="width:90%;margin:40px auto;">
    <div id="leftDiv" style="width:50%;background:yellow;height:200px;float:left;">
        <h3> It'S A GAME </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="rightDiv" style="width:50%;background:black;height:200px;float:right;">
        <h3 style="color:white"> It'S A TUTORIAL </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#leftDiv").hoverIntent(function () {
            jQuery("#leftDiv").animate({"width":"100%"},1000);
            jQuery("#rightDiv").animate({"width":"0%"},1000);
        },
        function () {
            jQuery("#leftDiv").animate({"width":"50%"},1000);
            jQuery("#rightDiv").animate({"width":"50%"},1000);
        }
    );
    jQuery("#rightDiv").hoverIntent(function () {
            jQuery("#rightDiv").animate({"width":"100%"},1000);
            jQuery("#leftDiv").animate({"width":"0%"},1000);
        },
        function () {
            jQuery("#rightDiv").animate({"width":"50%"},1000);
            jQuery("#leftDiv").animate({"width":"50%"},1000);
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add two entries on `CSS` for Left Div and Right Div:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

Apart from that you are using `hoverIntent` which is not really required, just you can use `hover`

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/Lg96y/)**

With all these I have modified your HTML and JQuery as below

### HTML:

```
<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="leftDiv">
        <h3> It'S A GAME </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="rightDiv">
        <h3 style="color:white"> It'S A TUTORIAL </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

### JQuery:

```
$(".leftDiv").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).animate({"width": "100%"}, 1000);
        $(".rightDiv").animate({"width": "0%"}, 1000);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).animate({"width": "50%"}, 1000);
        $(".rightDiv").animate({"width": "50%"}, 1000);
});
$(".rightDiv").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).animate({"width": "100%"}, 1000);
        $(".leftDiv").animate({"width": "0%"}, 1000);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).animate({"width": "50%"}, 1000);
        $(".leftDiv").animate({"width": "50%"}, 1000);
});
```

### CSS:

```
.rightDiv {
    width: 50%;
    background: black;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.leftDiv {
    width: 50%;
    background: yellow;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.mainDiv {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 40px auto;
}
```

### UPDATE:

As your comments, you want to stop queuing of hover. Best way to fix is by using `.stop()` function and reduce the width little bit.

Refer **[LIVE DEMO - 2](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/Lg96y/1/)**

### JQuery:

```
$(".leftDiv").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"width": "100%"}, 1000);
        $(".rightDiv").stop().animate({"width": "0%"}, 1000);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"width": "49.3%"}, 1000);
        $(".rightDiv").stop().animate({"width": "49.3%"}, 1000);
});
$(".rightDiv").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"width": "100%"}, 1000);
        $(".leftDiv").stop().animate({"width": "0%"}, 1000);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"width": "49.3%"}, 1000);
        $(".leftDiv").stop().animate({"width": "49.3%"}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: hoverIntent preferable to hover because if I were to hover in/out the div for number of occasions in quick succession then the animations will be queued and will keep continuing till all of them are processed.

Comment: Hi, working in your jsfiddle but not working on my site http://42charts.com/home2 :(... any ideas why

Comment: @user1517108: On the demo, I used `jQuery 1.9.1` & `jQuery UI 1.9.2`

Comment: @user1517108: Still no need to use hoverIntent. Your main concern is to stop queuing the hover. To fix this queuing, you need to use `stop()` function. Refer the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the CSS and some of the script (basically remove 1% everywhere).

HTML

```
 <div style="width:90%;height:200px">
        <div id="leftDiv" style="width:49%;background:yellow;height:200px;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap">
            <h3> It'S A GAME </h3>
        </div>
        <div id="rightDiv" style="width:49%;background:black;height:200px;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap">
            <h3 style="color:white"> It'S A TUTORIAL </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#leftDiv").hoverIntent(function () {
                jQuery("#leftDiv").animate({"width":"99%"},1000);
                jQuery("#rightDiv").animate({"width":"0%"},1000);
            },
            function () {
                jQuery("#leftDiv").animate({"width":"49%"},1000);
                jQuery("#rightDiv").animate({"width":"49%"},1000);
            }
        );
        jQuery("#rightDiv").hoverIntent(function () {
                jQuery("#rightDiv").animate({"width":"99%"},1000);
                jQuery("#leftDiv").animate({"width":"0%"},1000);
            },
            function () {
                jQuery("#rightDiv").animate({"width":"49%"},1000);
                jQuery("#leftDiv").animate({"width":"49%"},1000);
            }
        );
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rm7S3/

Answer (score 1):

I understand you don't like the text wrapping when the animation is done. 
You can add the following css to prevent the text from breaking.

```
h3{
 white-space:nowrap;
}
```

[See updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WYFH5/6/)

Not part of the question but it is strongly advised to keep the styling in a css file and not inline (unless you get a performance hit). [See this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WYFH5/7/) as example

Comment: nearly correct - However overflow: hidden;  is also needed as in my browser I could still see part of the hidden Div's text. Upvote for this

Comment: @user1517108 That is correct. Even though I know I have to test in multiple browsers, I did test in google chrome only.

Answer (score 0):

1. when you're placing the div within div always **`inline-block`** as `display`.
2. Cover the `html` and `body` with **`100%`** width and height

   `html,body{
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
   }`

---

### Updates:

I have re factored your code to have a good look and understand of code.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="leftDiv">
            <h3> It'S A GAME </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="rightDiv">
            <h3 style="color:white"> It'S A TUTORIAL </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    width:90%;
    margin:40px auto;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    height:200px;
}
#leftDiv {
    width:50%;
    background:yellow;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
#rightDiv {
    width:50%;
    background:black;
    height:200px;
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

### [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WYFH5/11/)

Answer (score 0):

change the duration time of second animation to `970`

and use `width` as `100%` instead of `90%`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WYFH5/13/)